# scaling images in boxes

Tags: graphics

I wanted to use an image in a box and coded:

```
 \documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
 \usepackage[english]{babel}
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \begin{document}
 \fbox{
 \begin{minipage}{42em}
  \includegraphics{myimage.png}
  \end{minipage}
 }
 \end{document}
```

This code runs but my image is a bit large and goes out of the borders. When I tried to scale it by

```
 \fbox{
 \begin{minipage}{42em}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.1]{myimage.png}
  \end{minipage}
 }
```

got many error messages. Why could I not scale this image? Do I need any additional user-package?

Comment: It might be easier to specify `width=` or `height=` rather than `scale=`.  Also, pay attention if the bounding box of the figure is messed up.  Finally, there is a length `\fboxsep` that is used to place a blank border around the `\fbox` content.  Perhaps set that to 0pt.  One final comment: I'm not sure what purpose the `minipage` serves in your example (*i.e.*, you can place an `\fbox` around an `\includegraphics` directly).

Comment: did you use `graphics` or `graphicx` package (you are using the syntax of `graphicx`) you are also missing `%` at ends of lines

Comment: thank you @StevenB.Segletes. width and hight do not help for solving my problem. minipage in my example arranges borders appropriately to text, but probably tex has a much clever solution for doing that.

Comment: thank you @DavidCarlisle. I use graphicx package and edited my question after your remark

Comment: The code posted produces no error as long as a file `myimage.png` exists. Please ensure that the code you post generates the error and show the exact error lines from your log in a `{}` code block in the question. As it is, no one can really hope to guess what the problem is.

Comment: If you remove the minipage (and add the missing `%`) then the `\fbox` box will be around the image, which is more normal. With the minipage the box is forced to a certain width but the image does not fit it exactly.